# MySQL and PHP table not being created

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

HELP! Code not creating a table, does this look ok? How do you usually debug to find out what is not working in MySQL?

```
<?php  
// Connect to the file above here  
require "connect_to_mysql.php"; 

$sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE products (
id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
price VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
details text NOT NULL,
category varchar(64) NOT NULL,
date_added date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY product_name(product_name),
)";

mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: You should use a newer SQL extension (PDO or MySQLi for instance). The mysql extension is deprecated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last line doesn't need a comma `,`

```
$sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE products (
id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
price VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
details text NOT NULL,
category varchar(64) NOT NULL,
date_added date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY product_name(product_name)
)";
```

I tried out this code in phpMyAdmin first and found that error ^